# Which of these conduit connections meet the "within 12-inches" requirement?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, code-compliance, conduit, nec

IIRC, conduit and NM need to be supported within 12 inches of the panel (and again every 10' for conduit or 52" for NM).

Which of these panel attachments qualify for being supported "within 12-inches of the panel"?

It seems like all of these are examples that *should* be secure enough to meet the 12-inch rule, but I'd like to make sure!

## Outdoor 3R panels

### A. 2" IMC into raintight hub:

[image: IMC into raintight hub]

### B. 2" EMT into raintight NPT coupler threaded into to raintight hub:

[image: EMT into raintight NPT coupler threaded into to raintight hub]

## Indoor panels

### C. 2" EMT compression into panel connector:

[image: EMT compression into panel connector]

### D. NM clamp in a KO:

[image: NM clamp in a KO]

Comment: I don't know how the rules apply to rigid conduit, but the NM cable definitely needs to be secured. The clamp in the knockout doesn't count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two terms you need to separate and identify: "securel fastened," and "supported." It all boils down to the wiring method you choose.

For example, Romex must be as securely fastened within 12" of any termination point. It reduces to 8" when there's no clamp,
such as a Carlon blue box. And then *supported* every 4-1/2 ft.

What's the difference between these terms? Well, see securely fastened means you can't pull the cable or conduit laterally in either direction. While supported simply means held up and prevented from sagging.

Here's an example. You have a ceiling box mounted in a basement ceiling joist. You should staple the Romex within 12" of the ceiling box with integral clamp. You then run the Romex through bored holes through the joists, 16" O.C.

The end result is your Romex is "securely fastened* within 12* and supported every 16".

Now with EMT, IMC, or rigid, you need to securely fasten within 3ft and support every 10 ft. There's also an exception in the code where if there is no structural framing within 3ft, you can go up to 5ft.

So to reiterate:

Securely fastened: prevention from pulling out.

Supported: being held up.

Comment: For clarification, please: "Now with EMT, IMC, _of_ rigid", or should that be "Now with EMT, IMC, _or_ rigid"? If the former, of rigid what? (Yes, I know, I'm the typo police, but I'm trying to learn stuff and those typos can lead to confusion.) Other than that, I consider this very useful and it taught me stuff I didn't know, so thank you!

Comment: Also copy-pasting @longneck's comment here: "[...] the NM cable definitely needs to be secured. The clamp in the knockout doesn't count."

Comment: Typos fixed. Yes, NM needs to be secured regardless of whether or not there's a clamp. It's within 12" with a clamp or 8" without a clamp.

Answer (score 4):

### 12" is correct for NM but not conduit

Your 12" rule is correct for NM; however, rigid conduits are permitted to have the first support strap/clamp anywhere within 3' of the termination.  Note, though, that this is a support to the *structure* as its intended to prevent excessive strain on the clamp or termination to the box or cabinet.

### But, that second picture is no good for unrelated reasons

There is an issue with the second picture, but it has naught to do with conduit support.  Instead, what you have there is an EMT threaded compression connector screwed into a threaded (bolt-on) hub fitting.  This is a configuration that is *not* tested by UL or covered by the relevant product standards, and thus is not guaranteed to provide adequate watertightness or grounding and bonding continuity.

Depending on local AHJ approval, you *may* be able to use a EMT fitting with NPT threads (the Garvin raintight compression fittings say in their [drawings](https://assets.southwire.com/ImConvServlet/imconv/e21128093d94fe61a45d43699886a1ec66e2c03b/origin?assetDescr=ds-ccnr-250) that they use such, but you'd have to check a fitting to be sure) threaded into that hub, or use some sort of raintight EMT-rigid transition fitting such as the Amfico ETR series to adapt the EMT to a rigid nipple that then threads into the hub.  (Most other manufacturers stop their raintight EMT-rigid transitions at 1".)